# variable within a nested loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to figure what the values of `xcoord_orig` and `ycoord_orig` are when the last conditional statement is true i.e. when `board[xcoordT][ycoordT] == computer`.  I feel that as I have it right now, I'm simply printing their values if the conditional statement is true.  But what I really want are the values of `xcoord_orig` and `ycoord_orig` under the first loop at the point where the last conditional statement is true.  I'm not sure if this is clear but I thought I would ask.

```
for num in range(8):
    for i in range(len(valid_list)):

        xcoord_orig = valid_list[i][0]
        ycoord_orig = valid_list[i][1]
        xcoord1 = valid_list[i][0] + num_list[num]
        ycoord1 = valid_list[i][1] + num_list2[num]

        if 0 <= xcoord1 <= 7 and 0 <= ycoord1 <= 7:
            piece = board[xcoord1][ycoord1]
            if piece == player:

                move_list = []

                for i in range(2,8):
                    xcoordT = xcoord_orig
                    ycoordT = ycoord_orig - i
                    print(xcoord_orig, ycoord_orig)
                    if board[xcoordT][ycoordT] == computer:
                        move_list.append([xcoordT, ycoordT])
                        print(xcoord_orig, ycoord_orig)
```

Comment: So did you want the actual values in separate variables? I'm a bit confused mate.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for i in range(len(valid_list)):
    ...    
        for i in range(2,8):
```

Is epic fail.  It can't be correct.

Comment: you mean reusing i or something else?

Comment: @seekingjannah:  You can't reuse variables randomly.  Variables have *meaning* which you should be able to state clearly, completely and precisely.  And the meaning of a variable in a given scope **cannot** ever change.  `i` can't mean two different things in the two loops.  That's just impossible to make sense of.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the reusing variables error.  I changed it but it still doesn't fix my problem :(.  In fact, it doesn't seem to make any difference at all.

Comment: I'm not saying reusing variables is a smart idea, but since the inner `for` block doesn't reference the outer value of `i`, and there is no code in the outer block after the inner one, it doesn't matter in this case.